# React styling in Rebass - css prefix?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I played with rebass for few day, and i am thinking use rebass for my future project, but i'm not sure if rebass have some way how to handle css prefix. Is there anybody who worked with Rebass and have some experience with that?

In the documentation I could not find anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Rebass is built with Styled-Components, and they have it set up so all CSS rules are automatically vendor prefixed.

The official word from the Styled-Components docs:
"The CSS rules are automatically vendor prefixed, so you don't have to think about it."